# Bitnami EC2 Parse Server Instance, change the default email files

Tags: amazon-ec2, parse-platform, parse-server, bitnami, reset-password

I have correctly managed to set up reset email using a mailgun adapter on my Bitnami EC2 Parse Server, where once a user forget his or her password on the android app, they can reset the password via Parse. However, after opening the email, the user gets taken to a page entirely in English. Specifically: DOMAIN.COM/parse/apps/choose_password.

The text is as follows:

Reset Your Password for APP NAME
New Password for USER
New Password

Confirm New Password
Change Password

My question is, how can I edit this page to be in a different language? It is probably a case of finding the file on the server, but I have not been able to find it. I am using the following server:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Bitnami-Parse-Server-Certified-by-Bitnami/B01BLQ17TO

Thanks for your trouble helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default pages using [these](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#custom-pages) options when initializing Parse Server:

```js
var server = ParseServer({
  ...otherOptions,

  customPages: {
    passwordResetSuccess: "http://yourapp.com/passwordResetSuccess",
    verifyEmailSuccess: "http://yourapp.com/verifyEmailSuccess",
    parseFrameURL: "http://yourapp.com/parseFrameURL",
    linkSendSuccess: "http://yourapp.com/linkSendSuccess",
    linkSendFail: "http://yourapp.com/linkSendFail",
    invalidLink: "http://yourapp.com/invalidLink",
    invalidVerificationLink: "http://yourapp.com/invalidVerificationLink",
    choosePassword: "http://yourapp.com/choosePassword"
  }
})
```

You can find the default ones to be used as templates [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/tree/master/public_html).